# Entry point not found when loading raster

Tags: r, raster, r-raster

I have recently installed the `raster` package and when I unpack the package using the `library` function, this message always appears:

[image]

Session Info:

```
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils    
[5] datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] sp_1.4-2    dplyr_0.8.5 auk_0.4.1  

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_1.0.4.6     rstudioapi_0.11 
 [3] magrittr_1.5     hms_0.5.3       
 [5] tidyselect_1.0.0 lattice_0.20-41 
 [7] R6_2.4.1         rlang_0.4.5     
 [9] stringr_1.4.0    tools_4.0.0     
[11] grid_4.0.0       ellipsis_0.3.0  
[13] assertthat_0.2.1 tibble_3.0.1    
[15] lifecycle_0.2.0  crayon_1.3.4    
[17] purrr_0.3.4      readr_1.3.1     
[19] vctrs_0.2.4      glue_1.4.0      
[21] stringi_1.4.6    compiler_4.0.0  
[23] pillar_1.4.4     pkgconfig_2.0.3
```

As you can imagine, it fails to load as a result. How can I fix this?

Comment: First thing to try would be re-install raster.  If that fails, please provide your `sessionInfo()`

Comment: Re-install does not work. I have provided the session info

Comment: The session info is incomplete, it does not show the R version. It does show that you have a lot of packages loaded. That points to a possible source of this problem (using a save workspace) You should start with a clean environment with no packages loaded.  Once you have no packages loaded (except for the base packages) you can try again.  One approach to cleaning up your session is to run `unlink(".Rdata")` and then close R *without* save  the workspace; and then load R again.  And then reinstall Rcpp and raster

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a similar problem. My solution was to update R and re-install the raster package.